# Convert java encryption method in php

Tags: java, php, encryption

Below is the encryption method written in java, which I am trying to convert in php.

```
public static String encryptWithAesCtrNoPadding(final String key, final String value)
throws IOException {
    try {
        byte[] encKey = Arrays.copyOf(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), 16);
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(encKey, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
        return Hex.encodeHexString(cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IOException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I tried several ways explained online but encrypted values from both the functions are not matching.

Below is the closest solution I got so far, but not getting the required output.

```
<?php

function do_encryption(String $key, String $value)
{

    $iv = "0000000000000000"; //base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-128-cbc')));

    $encodedEncryptedData = bin2hex(openssl_encrypt($value, "AES-128-CTR", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, substr(($iv) , 0, 16)));
}

do_encryption("secret", "1234567890");

?>
```

Any help in resolving this is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you expect a "matching" output when there is a random element (see "openssl_random_pseudo_bytes") - for testing purposes I recommend a "fixed IV" of 16 x00's on Java AND PHP side.

Comment: @MichaelFehr yes I have been doing testing on fixed iv only. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry but your IV's differ: on Java it's an array of 16 bytes filled with (hex) x00, the PHP side has 16 bytes filled with (hex) x30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's AES CTR implementation and PHP OpenSSL's AES CTR implementations gives the same ciphertext when feed with the same data (encryption key, initialization vector and plaintext).

Below you find both programs using an **UNSECURE fixed IV** (for demonstration purposes) - never ever use a fixed IV in real programs!

The result on Java-side is:

```
ciphertext (hex): 8cddfd68b61265f7d9bb36a058e9405ad15c7797a322ef8c4e4788b5c31508aec8917f7c17234e757d7e38
```

and the same result on PHP-side:

```
ciphertext (hex): 8cddfd68b61265f7d9bb36a058e9405ad15c7797a322ef8c4e4788b5c31508aec8917f7c17234e757d7e38
```

**Security warning**: the following codes use a static IV and static (hardcoded) key and are for educational purpose only:

Java:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String encryptionKey = "1234567890123456";
        String plaintext = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
        String ciphertext = encryptWithAesCtrNoPadding(encryptionKey, plaintext);
        System.out.println("ciphertext (hex): " + ciphertext);
        // result: 8cddfd68b61265f7d9bb36a058e9405ad15c7797a322ef8c4e4788b5c31508aec8917f7c17234e757d7e38
    }

    public static String encryptWithAesCtrNoPadding(final String key, final String value)
            throws IOException {
        try {
            byte[] encKey = Arrays.copyOf(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), 16);
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(encKey, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
            // ### security warning: never use a STATIC IV ###
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
            return Hex.encodeHexString(cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IOException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
function do_encryption(String $key, String $value)
{
    // ### security warning: never use a STATIC IV ###
    $fixedIv =  "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00";
    //$iv = "0000000000000000"; //base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-128-cbc')));
    $encodedEncryptedData = bin2hex(openssl_encrypt($value, "AES-128-CTR", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, substr(($fixedIv) , 0, 16)));
    return $encodedEncryptedData;
}
$encryptionKey = "1234567890123456";
$plaintext = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$ciphertext = do_encryption($encryptionKey, $plaintext);
echo 'ciphertext (hex): ' . $ciphertext;
// result 8cddfd68b61265f7d9bb36a058e9405ad15c7797a322ef8c4e4788b5c31508aec8917f7c17234e757d7e38
// java   8cddfd68b61265f7d9bb36a058e9405ad15c7797a322ef8c4e4788b5c31508aec8917f7c17234e757d7e38
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked for me.. I will ensure we use dynamic IV for the encryption.